# Changing states of buttons built using css + png

Tags: html, css, png, state

I'm trying to build styles for my buttons in the most efficient way. I have a class called `.button-small` that contain all the colors and dims for the buttons:

```
.button-small {
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #59aeee 1%,#4ea0dc 100%); /* W3C */
border-radius: 3px;
cursor: pointer;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
}
```

To that class I'd like to add all required states, `.button-small:active` etc.

Now that is a simple part, the struggle comes next. I have several buttons and all of them have different `png` file, so I decided to create separate classes that would hold only additional information about image url, that is:

```
.user-chat {
background: url('images/userchat.png') center center no-repeat;
}
```

The problem with above is once applied to the HTML code, `<div class="button-small user-chat"></div>`, `background:` property is stripping off information about the color from the main `.button-small` class. I know I could add information about background to the code, which I did previously:

```
.user-chat {
background: url('images/userchat.png') center center no-repeat, linear-gradient(to bottom,  #73b5e7 1%,#429be0 100%)`
}
```

But than in order to add different button states to the code, I'd have to duplicate the code for each button, and since I have approximately 30 of them, that wouldn't be very efficient.

So what I'm really after is a line of code that would allow me to insert different transparent-background `png` images on top of the button, regardless the button's state. Is there such thing, and if not, what would be the most efficient way to get the job done?

Comment: You need to google CSS & sprites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may wish to consider the use of pseudo elements. It's what I usually do when I need multiple background images like you're after.

You could do something similar to this:

```
.button-small {
    position: relative; /* So we can position our ::before element as needed */
}

/* Generic styles for pseudo elements */
.button-small::before {
    content: ''; /* required for pseudo elements to work */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

/* You would now add your additional classes */
.user-chat::before {
    background: url(../something/goes/here.png) center center no-repeat;
}
```

This code *should* work in IE9 upwards. If you're supporting IE8, use `:before` instead of `::before`.

For the hover and active states, you could do:

```
.user-chat:hover::before,
.user-chat:active::before,
.user-chat:focus::before {
    background-image: url(new/image.png); 
    /* Only need to override the image URL if position stays the same */
}
```

Comment: Had to read more about ::before and ::after, tweaked your solution a bit and ended up applying content png image to `.user-chat::before` class style. Worked perfectly, thanks for help

Comment: No worries, if you need any other help let me know!